# Test method which throws an exception as has Span as a parameter

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I want to test a method with NUnit's `Assert.Throws<>`. This method has `Span` in the parameters. A typical approach is similar to the code below:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldThrowExceptionIfSomething()
{
  // GIVEN
  var byteArray = ...;
  var mySpan = byteArray.AsSpan();

  // WHEN-THEN
  Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => Foo.DoSomethingWithSpan(mySpan));
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't compile with error:

> [CS8175] Cannot use ref local 'mySpan' inside an anonymous method,
>   lambda expression, or query expression

I appreciate any suggestions about testing these kinds of methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spans are stack-only types, and can't be captured by lambdas.

You'll need to get the Span inside the lambda:

```
var byteArray = ...;
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => Foo.DoSomethingWithSpan(byteArray.AsSpan()));
```